# Как реализовать функцию insert в LinkedList?

Tags: java

Метод insert добавляет элемент на определенную позицию, сместив остальные вправо. 
Вот мой код:

```
public void insert(Object data, int index) {


    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.toString(index));
    }



    Node node = new Node(null,data);  

    Node cur = head ;  // ссылка на начало 


    if (index == 0) {
        if (size == 0) {
            head = node;

            size = 1;
        } else {
            node.next = head;

            head = node;
            size++;
        }
    }



    else{
    for(int i = 0 ; i<index && cur.next!=null ; i++) // находим элемент с этим индексом
        cur = cur.next ; 





    node.next = cur ; // говорим , что после вставляемого элемента, будет cur

















     size++; 
    } 







}
```

Но предполагаю, что проблема в том , что я не написал после какого элемента будет расположен вставляемый(новый) элемент. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Все просто  LinkedList - это реализация алгоритма связного списка.
У него есть стандартный метод:

```
void add(int index, E element)
```

который : Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

По спецификации он и так его вставит со сдвигом всех элементов в права

Если у Вас есть желание написать собственный метод вставки тогда : 
Класс LinkedList включает статический внутренний класс Entry, с помощью которого создаются новые элементы.

```
private static class Entry<E>{
    E element;
    Entry<E> next;
    Entry<E> prev;

    Entry(E element, Entry<E> next, Entry<E> prev){
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

Для добавления нового элемента в LinkedList необходимо выполнить две итерации:

1. создать экземпляр класса Entry;
2. переопределять указатели на предыдущий и следующий элемент.